# Change the scope of routes to 'admin' for specific actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a category model and in my routes.rb, I have

```
resources :categories
```

which generates the following set of routes.

```
categories_path      GET     /categories(.:format)           categories#index
                     POST    /categories(.:format)           categories#create
new_category_path    GET     /categories/new(.:format)       categories#new
edit_category_path   GET     /categories/:id/edit(.:format)  categories#edit
category_path        GET     /categories/:id(.:format)       categories#show
                     PATCH   /categories/:id(.:format)       categories#update
                     PUT     /categories/:id(.:format)       categories#update
                     DELETE  /categories/:id(.:format)       categories#destroy
```

Now, what I need is except for all GET routes, I want the rest of the routes to be under '/admin' scope. So that operations like create, edit and delete are accessed at admin/categories/:id/edit etc.

Is there an easy way to mention this scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to organize groups of controllers under a namespace. Most commonly, you might group a number of administrative controllers under an admin namespace. You would place these controllers under the `app/controllers/admin` directory, and you can group them together in your router:

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

This will create a number of routes for each of the posts and comments controller. For `Admin::PostsController`, Rails will create:

```
GET       /admin/posts
GET       /admin/posts/new
POST      /admin/posts
GET       /admin/posts/1
GET       /admin/posts/1/edit
PATCH/PUT /admin/posts/1
DELETE    /admin/posts/1
```

check the rest of it through the [apidock documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I want the GET urls to be accessed without the namespace and the rest with namespace. how do I that?

Comment: how about try to add `:except => [:index, :new]` and see if this will work so it will be like this `resources :posts , :except => [:index, :new]` and not sure about this but nothing will be without trying , making another namespace for the non-admin actions `resources :posts , :only => [:index, :new]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define route of categories twice.

```
resources :categories, :only => :index
resources :categories, :except => :index, :path => 'admin/categories'
```